# Pre-Populating fields on vf page based on ret URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a vf page tied to a force.com site which is being used at different places on my company website like support FAQ page, new account request etc and I want to pre populate the subject field on my vf page based on the page the user is redirected from.

Is this possible?

This is what i have now `<apex:inputField required="true" value="{!c.Subject}" id="subject" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You should implement a controller Extension that modifies the field subject of your object if is there a "subject" parameter in the url, just something as following:

```
public class CustomExtension {
    Private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    Private Case c;

    public CustomExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.stdController = stdController;
        c = (case)this.stdController.getRecord();

        //Perform actions...
        updateSubject();

    }

    private void updateSubject() {
        // Check if param exists and assign it.
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('subject')) {
            c.subject = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('subject');
        }
    }
}
```

The url should contain your parameter, something as following...

```
/apex/CustomVisualforce?id=5001i000003COdIAAW&subject=My%20Subject
```

Comment: Hi Dahn, thanks for your response, my force.com site is https://XXX-XXXX.csxx.force.com/form which is hosted on https://mycompanydomain.com/support.
Now when a user is redirected to my force.com site from my company's support page, i want the subject field on my vf page to pre-populate to 'support'. I tried ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL') but debug logs return NULL for retURL

Comment: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('YourGetParamName'). This function returns for your GET param name. Your GET param name is defined before the "=". In your previous case: subject=My%20Subject. If you wanted to add a param to your url called 'support' you should append at the end of your url "&support=yourValue" (without quotes, for instance: /apex/CustomVisualforce?id=5001i000003COdIAAW&subject=My%20Subject&support=My%20Support%20Value) and assign it to your variable binded to your visualforce.